# TypeError: fit() argument after ** must be a mapping, not NoneType

Tags: python, apache-spark, scikit-learn

I am trying to run the sample code in [spark_sklearn](https://github.com/databricks/spark-sklearn)

```
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from pyspark import SparkContext
from spark_sklearn import GridSearchCV
iris = datasets.load_iris()
parameters = {'kernel':('linear', 'rbf'), 'C':[1, 10]}
svr = svm.SVC()
sc = SparkContext()
clf = GridSearchCV(sc, svr, parameters)
clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
```

which throws a TypeError, full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
"<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
"spark_sklearn/grid_search.py", line 272, in fit
return self._fit(X, y, groups, ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
"spark_sklearn/grid_search.py", line 400, in _fit
best_estimator.fit(X, y, **fit_params)
TypeError: fit() argument after ** must be a mapping, not NoneType
```

I looked in the issues in the repo, but there was nothing like this. Can someone help me out with this?

```
Environment Info:
python 3.5.2
spark 2.2.0
spark_sklearn 0.2.0
```

Comment: It must be an instal issue. Please provide additional info, e.g: python version, version of spark-sklearn. Is your PYTHONPATH env is set accordingly? etc. You have to make sure anyone has enough info to be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is no ```sc``` defined (in the official example) and the docstring is incompatible with the [internal code](https://github.com/databricks/spark-sklearn/blob/3dc69d95b082d59cb5b19a56fe0b4f16b8d8c0c5/python/spark_sklearn/grid_search.py#L25) of spark_sklearn.GridSearchCV. For me a strong reason not to use it.

Comment: I have the same problem with python 2.7

Answer (score 2):

This issue is due to spark-sklearn's use of scikit-learn APIs that were deprecated in scikit-learn 0.19.0.

For now a workaround is to manually set clf.fit_params to an empty dict if you don't intend to pass any extra params to the fit method of the estimator being cross-validated

```
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from pyspark import SparkContext
from spark_sklearn import GridSearchCV
iris = datasets.load_iris()
parameters = {'kernel':('linear', 'rbf'), 'C':[1, 10]}
svr = svm.SVC()
sc = SparkContext()
clf = GridSearchCV(sc, svr, parameters)
clf.fit_params = {}
clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
```

Comment: Setting to an empty dict `{}` works well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue running my script. 
Are you sure you have spark_sklearn 0.2.0 ? 0.2.1 version is available for few days, and after having updated this package I had exactely the same error.

You can try in the terminal:

> pip uninstall spark-sklearn 
>   pip install spark-sklearn==0.2.0

It works for me. Good luck !

---